# Minority carrier current in p-n junction diode

Tags: pn-junction

Does minority carrier current flow through p-n junction even in the absence of any external applied voltage?Is minority carrier current same as reverse saturation current?

Comment: A *net* current flow cannot occur since it will lead to charge accumulation. Any minority carrier flow from P to N will be *on average* cancelled by minority carrier flow from N to P if there is no applied field.

Comment: Same cause but temperature dependance